# Why do linear momentum and angular momentum have to be conserved in ground frame only?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation, rotational-kinematics

According the Newton's second law of translational and rotational motion respectively if the net external force /torque acting on a body is zero then the linear/angluar momentum is a constant . So when we do conserve them why do we always conserve them in the ground reference frame ? If we do conserve them in a nonintertial reference frame do we have to apply some kind of pseudo force ? ( if yes where and of what ?)

Comment: Er ... you can conserve them in other inertial frames, too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force